# hibernate.cfg.xml contains info about MySQL database they why I am getting this exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

This is question about java hibernate.

my `hibernate.cfg.xml` is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/poc</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"/>
    <mapping class="test.person" file="" jar="" package="" resource="person.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Connection to the database is working and I can explore databases and tables,

my sample

`person.hbm.xml` is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="test.person" table="person">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="id" >
            <generator class="assigned"/>
        </id>
        <property name="fName">
            <column name="fName" />
        </property>
        <property name="lName">
            <column name="lName"/>
        </property>
        <property name="age">
            <column name="age"/>
        </property>
        <property name="gender">
            <column name="gender"/>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

this is my person class

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package test;

public class person {

    private int id;
    private String fName;
    private String lName;
    private String gender;
    private int age;

    public person() {
        System.out.println("person");
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getfName() {
        return fName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public String getlName() {
        return lName;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setfName(String fName) {
        this.fName = fName;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public void setlName(String lName) {
        this.lName = lName;
    }

}
```

Here comes my Main class

```
package test;


import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {


        Session session = null;
        SessionFactory sessionFactory =new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        person obj = new person();
        obj.setfName("Aqif");
        obj.setlName("Hamid");
        obj.setAge(24);
        obj.setGender("Male");

        session.save(obj);
        session.flush();
        session.close();

    }
}
```

I am getting this exception,

```
SEVERE: JDBC Driver class not found: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:61)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: JDBC Driver class not found: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.newConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderFactory.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createConnectionProvider(SettingsFactory.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2009)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1292)
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
    at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:61)
    ... 7 more
Java Result: 1
```

Please help me resolve these exceptions

I donot know why I am getting this exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
```

Where as my hibernate.cfg.xml is set for MySQL database

---

EDIT:

Location of files,

It is located at root of .java files

C:.....NetBeansProjects\test\src

That is src folder of my project.

and java files are in

C:.....NetBeansProjects\test\src\test

I have tried by coping my hibernate.cfg.xml file to some other locations as well.

Comment: Where is your `hibernate.cfx.xml` located?

Comment: It is located at root of .java files

NetBeansProjects\test\src

That is src folder of my project.

I have tried by coping my hibernate.cfg.xml file to some other locations as well.

Comment: -1 for person not being named Person.  It is pretty standard in Java to have class names capitalized.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` must be present in the root of the classpath. Hibernate uses the current thread's context classloader, to locate and load this file. This would mean that:

- If the `Test` class is within a JAR, then the config file, must be at the root of the JAR.
- If the `Test` class is in a directory, say `/classes/test/Test.class`, then `hibernate.cfg.xml` must be present in `/classes`.

Your current issue would most likely be due to another `hibernate.cfg.xml` file being located and loaded by Hibernate. This is possible if no configuration file was found in the root of your class path; Hibernate then delegates the loading of the configuration file to the `Environment` class' classloader, until it locates a configuration file. To avoid this, you must ensure that your desired config file, with the MySQL related properties, must be present in the root of your classpath.

Comment: Or put your configuration in `mysql-hibernate.cfg.xml` and call `configure("mysql-hibernate.cfg.xml")`

Comment: @Aqif, those are the directories of your source files. You'll need to ensure that the config file is copied into the runtime classpath directory or JAR. Your IDE may or may not do that for you.

Comment: Thank you

configure("mysql-hibernate.cfg.xml") worked for me.

But I am curious why it is not working with 

configure() while using default name, hibernate.cfg.xml and yes they gets copied in build

Build folder contains hibernate cfg and mapping files and a sub directory of .class files

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong `hibernate.cfg.xml`. It should be located in your `src`, not in a package/subdir.

Answer (score 1):

First of all change your class name as in correct format of java .
 Replace the class name "person" to "Person".
And now change the default Database of eclips to the the required Database to which you want to connect by follow
[Hibernate Tutorial 02 - Setting Up Hibernate](http://javabrains.koushik.org/2011/06/hibernate-tutorial-02-setting-up.html) 
and 
[Hibernate Tutorial 03 Part 1- Writing a Hibernate Application](http://javabrains.koushik.org/2011/06/hibernate-tutorial-03-part-1-writing.html)

After completion of connection mechanism, please verify your Database connection with the help of pin option in eclips...
Now it's ready to connect with you DB with Hibernate ...

Answer (score 1):

Put hibernate.cfg.xml in the root of classpath and 
set jar files in the classpath
Then It wil work.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you given configuration to session factory, it will not create session object with mapping and database info. So just create the configuration by passing hibernate.cfg.xml

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");// populates the data         
                                    // configuration file

// creating seession factory object
SessionFactory factory = cfg.buildSessionFactory();

// creating session object
Session session = factory.openSession();
```